# ATI Graphics Card detected as different card Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, graphics, amd-graphics, switchable-graphics

I ran the code`sudo lshw -c display` to get the model of my graphics card that I am using. It showed Whistler 6600M series along with my Intel HD Graphics. I have switchable graphics. But my graphics card is HD 6750M. Why would it be shown differently and how to rectify this?

Output of `lspci -nnk | grepVGA -A1`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd
Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
[8086:0116] (rev 09) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device
[103c:1646]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series] [1002:6741] (rev ff)
  Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Which driver have you installed?openn source or the one from amd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devices are named after what they are in the PCI ID database. Look at [the database entry for this device](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/1002/6741).

On 2013-03-16 it was updated from `Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]` to `Whistler [Radeon HD 6600M/6700M Series]` and there have been a ton of updates since.

On my computer it shows `Whistler [Radeon HD 6600M/6700M/7600M Series]`.

---

Why is this? Well if you look at your `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids` file, you'll see when it was last updated. Why is yours old? Because you're using an older version of Ubuntu, probably. I doubt they'd backport an insignificant package like `hwdata`. Here's my version for your reference.

```
$ apt-cache policy hwdata
hwdata:
  Installed: 0.234-1
  Candidate: 0.234-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.234-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

What I should really underline is ***this doesn't matter even a tiny little bit***. Hardware lookups should only be being done on the ID (the `[1002:6741]`) so there's really nothing to worry about. It's just *calling* it the wrong name.

Comment: For me it shows installed: 0.233-1. So it must be an old one. Actually I asked this question because I thought this was the reason why I have got black screen repeated times trying to install catalyst center according to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450. Thanks.

Comment: BTW How would I update this "hwdata"?

Comment: I don't think a simple upgrade is provided for 12.04. You *could* nab the version from 12.10 or 13.04 [from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/hwdata) (see Binary Packages on the right) but frankly, it would just update your database. It won't fix anything.